# Edits on answers

Tags: support

I just went through an edit (no big deal) of one of my answers and had a very hard time understanding exactly what and why it was edited.  Lost quite a few points (again no big deal) but I couldn't make out what was wrong, what was changed.  I make mistakes but I do write well.  This was all over the place.  When I make a mistake I want to learn from it or walk away from it shrugging my shoulders as just a simple mistake.  This computer's cursor is constantly jumping around, need to get a new mouse.  I just would like to be able to make sense of an edit.  Grin.

Comment: Link? (If it wasn't [this](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/9917/26), that is.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example: [Why are strawberries cooled before planting, and what is a term for this procedure?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/13346/why-are-strawberries-cooled-before-planting-and-what-is-a-term-for-this-procedu) I [edited Jul 13 at 19:44](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/posts/13346/revisions) (click to view edit). The heading says, 'deleted 50 characters in body; edited tags; edited title', and below that, it shows exactly what I did. Below that there will be previous edits, if any, which you can click on to view, and at the bottom, there will be the original untouched post.

If you don't like a certain edit, you can do a roll-back, to an older edit or to the original post. If the post in question was the one Niall C. linked to, I'm not sure why Tea Drinker readded the removed info.